# How to have only the latest instance of certain plotted lines visible?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

First: I'm pretty sure this is my poor understanding of how things work

I'm trying to plot a a "solid channel" with two horizontal straight lines as the upper and lower limits (red lines), and two straight horizontal lines that mark the first and the forth "forths" of the range between the upper and lower limits (the blue lines).

I was able to plot them. The problem is: I'd like to have only the last instance of these lines in the screen (based on the lookback period), but most of the time there are many of them.

Below you can see the code. And below the code, you can see in the first screenshot what I expect, and in the second and third screenshots you can see how it usually looks like.

Question is: how can I always have only one instance (the latest one) of this channel in the screen (i.e. only the four expected lines, two red and two blue)?

Any help will be highly appreciated! Cheers!

```
lookBack = 24
range = 4

highestHigh = highest(high, lookBack)
lowestLow = lowest(low, lookBack)

xAxisStartAt = bar_index[lookBack]
xAxisFinishesAt = bar_index

uppperLimit = highestHigh
lowerLimit = lowestLow

upperRange = ((highestHigh - lowestLow)/range) + lowestLow
lowerRange = highestHigh - ((highestHigh - lowestLow)/range)

// PAINTBRUSH
line.new(xAxisStartAt, uppperLimit, xAxisFinishesAt, uppperLimit, color=color.red, width= 3, extend=extend.none)
line.new(xAxisStartAt, lowerLimit, xAxisFinishesAt, lowerLimit, color=color.red, width= 3, extend=extend.none)
line.new(xAxisStartAt, upperRange, xAxisFinishesAt, upperRange, color=color.blue, width= 1, extend=extend.none)
line.new(xAxisStartAt, lowerRange, xAxisFinishesAt, lowerRange, color=color.blue, width= 1, extend=extend.none)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define your lines once, and then move the instances of the lines with `line.set_xy1()` and `line.set_xy2()`

```
//@version=4
study("TEST", overlay=true)

var ul = line.new(na, na, na, na, color=color.red,  width= 3, extend=extend.none)
var ll = line.new(na, na, na, na, color=color.red,  width= 3, extend=extend.none)
var ur = line.new(na, na, na, na, color=color.blue, width= 1, extend=extend.none)
var lr = line.new(na, na, na, na, color=color.blue, width= 1, extend=extend.none)

lookBack = 24
range = 4

highestHigh = highest(high, lookBack)
lowestLow = lowest(low, lookBack)

xAxisStartAt = bar_index[lookBack]
xAxisFinishesAt = bar_index

upperLimit = highestHigh
lowerLimit = lowestLow

upperRange = ((highestHigh - lowestLow)/range) + lowestLow
lowerRange = highestHigh - ((highestHigh - lowestLow)/range)

// PAINTBRUSH
line.set_xy1(ul, xAxisStartAt,    upperLimit)
line.set_xy2(ul, xAxisFinishesAt, upperLimit)

line.set_xy1(ll, xAxisStartAt,    lowerLimit)
line.set_xy2(ll, xAxisFinishesAt, lowerLimit)

line.set_xy1(ur, xAxisStartAt,    upperRange)
line.set_xy2(ur, xAxisFinishesAt, upperRange)

line.set_xy1(lr, xAxisStartAt,    lowerRange)
line.set_xy2(lr, xAxisFinishesAt, lowerRange)
```